# Django Admin: deactivate authentication

Tags: django, django-admin

I am using Django for a small one-person tool. I would like to add/adapt my models via the admin interface, but I don't want to login everytime.

How can I switch off the required authentication at /admin/?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I highly recommend **against** you doing down that road:

1. Is it possible? No; the admin relies on the django `auth` app being with your settings' `INSTALLED_APPS`; of course this is because the admin relies on permissions and permissions rely on the admin user being authenticated.
2. The admin is built to edit not simply "your" models but also the models enabling the admin itself, mainly the models exposed by the `auth` app itself.

*What to do* ... 2 options:

1. Quickly develop a simple solution requiring no authentication using Django's ModelForms - [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#modelform) and another good link [here](http://pydanny.com/core-concepts-django-modelforms.html).
2. If it's a "one-person tool" then simply keep your authentication details saved in the browser you use; i.e. let the browser remember your username and password, so you just have to hit the "login" button rather than re-enter your data.